# Effects of SWAP failure

Tags: swap

A team member has created a swapfile on one of our machines which needed more swap. And he created it on a filesystem on SSD. While our servers are not swapping a lot and probably safe to keep the swap file on the SSD with its finite write-cycles, I am curious to know what happens if SWAP partition fails on a server that is using the swap (say the SWAP drive died).

- Is a SWAP partition failure on a running machine catastrophic? Or it will be treated just like someone had issued a `swapoff -a` albeit without all the flushing of buffers and cache.
- I am assuming that the program that has its pages on SWAP may crash.
- If I am to reboot a machine with a failed SWAP, would commenting out the swap entries in fstab would suffice to prevent being stuck at boot? Can I just add a new swap partition and update the fstab entries and it will reboot as if nothing had happend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using linux here, partly because of the mention of `swapoff -a` but it's advisable to be explicit about this, either in the text of your question and/or via tags.

A swap failure will generate a memory fault in the process that had its memory paged out to the swap device, i.e. that process will be killed.

Rebooting a system with a failed swap device will simply give an error when the `swapon` is executed but the system will continue on without that swap device. You can then use another swap device either directly with `swapon /dev/whatever` and/or edit `/etc/fstab` and reboot and/or `swapon -a`.

Note you can also use a file as swap device:

```
# create a large enough file (1GB here)
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/SWAPFILE bs=1024k count=1024
# write swap signature to the file so that the kernel recognizes it
mkswap /var/SWAPFILE
# activate it
swapon /var/SWAPFILE
```